# Is my drone battery too large?

Tags: quadcopters, lipo-batteries

I'm new to the drone game.  I'm building an Arducopter S500,(2015) with 2212 KV920 max 1200 gram, brushless motors, 10/45 blades, SimonK ESC's, Lipo 5200  11.1V battery, and GPS 2.8. My controller is a FLYSKY FS-16X  6 channel.  As of this question, the total weight is 1294 grams. My question:  My battery weighs in at 394 grams.  Is that too heavy? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

All of the provided information points to a 'standard' DIY setup. A 11.1v battery (3S) is recommended for this setup. The **5200** is the capacity in milliamp hours (mAh) which more or less tells you how long it can fly between recharges.
There are 4 motors, so if each can lift 1200 grams the total weight of drone, battery and other equipment needs to be less than 4800 grams.